# Include multiple surrounding rows for a list of ids (ordered by id)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to select all rows that match a list of ids from my table including 2 rows before and 2 rows after. Ordered by id.

```
 ID | Value
 ---+----------
  1 | Value #1
  2 | Value #2
  3 | Value #3
  4 | Value #4
  5 | Value #5
  6 | Value #6
  7 | Value #7
  8 | Value #8
  9 | Value #9
 10 | Value #10
 11 | Value #11
 12 | Value #12
 13 | Value #13
 14 | Value #14
 17 | Value #17
 19 | Value #19
 20 | Value #20
 28 | Value #28
 29 | Value #29
 30 | Value #30
```

Now I've the query:

```
 SELECT `ID`, `Value` FROM `table` WHERE `ID` in (5, 14) ORDER BY `ID`;
```

How can I extend it to return also IDs 3, 4, 6, 7 and 12, 13, 17, 19? I don't know the exact ids. There may be gaps in the table. If 5 is no match, than 3, 4, 6 and 7 should not be returned.

I've already read all other questions relating "surrounding rows". But they are all dealing with ONE result, that should include surrounding rows.

Comment: What if, for example, 5 weren't in the table but 6 and 7 were? Would you still want to return them?

Comment: You can assign a rank to each row (effectively eliminating the need to gaps) and then join rows which are within a rank of two - nut mureiniks question is valid; would you still want adjacent rows returned if the target row was missing

Comment: If 5 is no match, than 3, 4, 6 and 7 should not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Value
FROM (
   SELECT ID, Value,
          @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS rn
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) AS v
   ORDER BY ID) AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT rn
   FROM (
      SELECT ID, Value,
             @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS v
      ORDER BY ID) AS t
   WHERE t.ID IN (5, 14)  
) AS t2 ON t1.rn  BETWEEN t2.rn - 2 AND t2.rn + 2
```

The above query uses variables twice: once to assign a row number to each record and a second time in order to filter surrounding records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1e9fd/1)

Comment: I think the sql server will create a full table copy in memory using this version. My table can have up to 10.000.000 rows. My be I've to introduce a `Index` column to avoid that copy all the time. But that's slow, when deleting a row.

Comment: @SuperNova Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support window functions, so there is no easy way to implement such a query. Did you try this query with your actual data?

Comment: Upgrade to MariaDB 10.2 and use its Windowing functions.  They are excellent for such queries.